# Can't use javascript variable inside nested function (jquery masonry plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, nested, jquery-masonry

I want to use a javascript variable to calculate the columnWidth variable of the jQuery Masonry plugin. When I view source on my page, I see the variable name in the javascript rather than the variables value.

http://jsfiddle.net/robflate/fS2yL/

Thanks

Comment: Sorry you need to elaborate on this. What is the fiddle not doing that you want it to do?

Comment: Your problem is that when you look at your source, you see " return containerWidth / columns; " and not " return containerWidth / 5; " ?

Comment: DieVarDump - That is correct. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is intepreted... it's normal that you see "return containerWidth / columns;" in your source code.

When the javascript will be interpreted, the value of "columns" will be used.

If it does not work, it's surelly because you set "columns" as a string ( "5" ) and not as an integer. The division can't be perfomed.

Comment: As I've just said in reply to another question relating to something similar, I'm sure everyone who knows that javascript doesn't update the source is thinking I must be stupid but I honestly never knew that. Thanks for the info and help.

Answer (score 0):

That is expected - source will show what you loaded, it won't change the values. See this jsfiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/PFw9u/

This will work as expected.